# MAX4053 IC, V+ & V- , suitable dual diode

Tags: diodes, surface-mount, rectifier, crystal

On the PCB of a multimeter with MAX4053, V+ & V- is from external dual diode, please tell what type of diode it must be.

A screenshot from the MAX 4053 datasheet is attached.

Need the type of  the dual 3 pin SMD (SOT 23.)

The PCB is powered by a 3 VDC battery.

[image]

Comment: Khalil Mohammad - Hi, Please note that when a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (offline sources (e.g. books / articles etc.) require a typical citation, see the linked rule). Thanks for naming the source as the datasheet, but please [edit] your question to add the appropriate link for it, as that is also required. Also remember to include appropriate references in future. Thanks.